# How to convert a virtual function/baseclass in C++ to C programming?

Tags: c++, c, virtual-functions

I have CPP files containing Virtual functions/virtual base class.  I want to convert it to C files[Though not a good idea, but my lecturer wants it to be converted].  Can anyone tell how it can be done? Is there any specific libraries in C to give something equivalent to C++ Virtual functions/base class?

Comment: Since this is a question your lecturer posed, I'm guessing he (or she) is expecting some research on your part.  Here's a pointer - C++ was originally implemented as a front-end to C (C with classes) via Cfront: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront

Comment: Try googling "Object Oriented C"

Comment: @Abhineet probably refers to Object-Oriented Programming With ANSI-C: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is to show the teacher that you understand what virtual functions do and how they work, by being able to write primitive code that does the same thing.

The explicit translation would be to add a pointer to function as a field of the struct, and this means you can have member call syntax in C !  I demonstrated this at the SD-89 software development conference, and got a lot of feedback that they didn't know you could do those kinds of things in C.

I'm sure you can figure out how to set the pointer to different functions to specify the behavior for each instance.  Don't go on until you understand that well.

To fully implement virtual functions like C++ typically does, only a single pointer is added to the structure and it points to a list of such indirection pointers.  That's a pain to do by hand 'cause they are all different signatures.  Once you get the hang of doing that (implementing C++ features in lower-level code) and thinking about the object model involved, you should be able to figure out how virtual base classes work.  Strustrup's C++ book gives an explanation of roughly how they work.  Look at any diagram of the class and see if that offers inspiration, thinking about how to "write that" instead of accepting that this is the semantics of the C++ class.

—John

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a research task, I'll not put everything for you. But, I'll hint something.

1. Virtual methods fantastically provide a way to achieve dynamic polymorphism which is essentially a concept of OOP thus C++. This achieves via virtual table which constructed by the compiler and will be active at run time. C itself does not have such concept. You can't 'fully' achieve the effects of virtual functions in C.
2. Still you can do something. Think about using function pointers, arrays, structures, pointer arithmetic.
3. When your so-called virtual function is called you have to additionally look up function pointers.

Think about a way and come with your idea then.

Answer (score 0):

http://syscall.org/doku.php/gobjectutorial/start <- This website gives details on how to define a class in C using GObjects as well on how to inherit virtual functions.